# How to round integer in java

Tags: java

I want to round the number 1732 to the nearest ten, hundred and thousand. I tried with Math round functions, but it was written only for float and double. How to do this for Integer? Is there any function in java?

Comment: Your chosen answer is edited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [**Precision**](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html) (Apache Commons Math 3.1.1)

```
Precision.round(double, scale); // return double
Precision.round(float, scale); // return float
```

Use [**MathUtils**](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html) (Apache Commons Math) - Older versions

```
MathUtils.round(double, scale); // return double
MathUtils.round(float, scale); // return float
```

**scale** - The number of digits to the right of the decimal point. (+/-)

---

> Discarded because method **round(float,
>   scale)** be used.

<strike>Math.round(MathUtils.round(1732, -1)); // nearest ten, 1730</strike>
<strike>Math.round(MathUtils.round(1732, -2)); // nearest hundred, 1700</strike> 
<strike>Math.round(MathUtils.round(1732, -3)); // nearest thousand, 2000</strike>

---

**Better solution**

```
int i = 1732;
MathUtils.round((double) i, -1); // nearest ten, 1730.0
MathUtils.round((double) i, -2); // nearest hundred, 1700.0
MathUtils.round((double) i, -3); // nearest thousand, 2000.0
```

Comment: How can I do that for the nearest 12?

Answer (score 28):

What rounding mechanism do you want to use? Here's a primitive approach, for positive numbers:

```
int roundedNumber = (number + 500) / 1000 * 1000;
```

This will bring something like 1499 to 1000 and 1500 to 2000.

If you could have negative numbers:

```
int offset = (number >= 0) ? 500 : -500;
int roundedNumber = (number + offset) / 1000 * 1000;
```

Comment: this here is the right approach: int r = ((int)((n + 500) / 1000)) * 1000 since only the casting to int cuts off the digits

Comment: there is not type defined in your approach for "number"! so it makes ALL sense my friend.

Comment: "number" is an integer. Read the original question again.

Answer (score 18):

```
(int)(Math.round( 1732 / 10.0) * 10)
```

`Math.round(double)` takes the `double` and then rounds up as an nearest integer. So, `1732` will become `173.2` (input parameter) on processing by `Math.round(1732 / 10.0)`. So the method rounds it like `173.0`. Then multiplying it with **10** `(Math.round( 1732 / 10.0) * 10)` gives the rounded down answer, which is `173.0` will then be casted to `int`.

Comment: I think 10D is what you mean instead of 10L. Isn't it? +1

Comment: well, it works but you are better explain how your answer works

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat, `Math.round(double)` takes the double and then rounds up as an integer. So, `1732` will become `173.2` on processing by `Math.round()`. So the method rounds it like `173.0`. Then multiplying it with 10 gives the rounded down answer.

Comment: @Sibidharan thanks for the explanation,  my comment was to make the people who see his post understand why his code solves the problem, you can edit the answer with your explanation.

Answer (score 9):

You could try:

```
int y = 1732;
int x = y - y % 10;
```

The result will be 1730.

**Edit**: This *doesn't answer* the question. It simply removes part of the number but doesn't "round to the nearest".

Comment: 1736 would also go to 1730, which wouldn't be the nearest ten.

Comment: ...and the result for 1739 will also be 1730.  Not most people's expectation for rounding.

Comment: @cherouvim: Well, at least you're still scoring all the upvotes :)

Comment: Add 5 to `y` before applying your snippet and you have the nearest in the common sense. Example 1736 -> 1741 -> 1740.

Comment: @EboMike Yes, damn the hardware engineer who noticed he could save some transistors by providing round-towards-zero division in place of Euclidean division.

Answer (score 4):

At nearest ten:

```
int i = 1986;
int result;

result = i%10 > 5 ? ((i/10)*10)+10 : (i/10)*10;
```

(Add zero's at will for hundred and thousand).

Comment: This rounds up the following number (when rounding to nearest 100) which should be rounded down: 170718 is rounded UP to 170800. Surely this should round DOWN to 170700?

Answer (score 2):

why not just check the unit digit... 
1. if it is less than or equal to 5, add 0 at the unit position and leave the number as it is.
2. if it is more than 5, increment the tens digit, add 0 at the unit position.

ex: 1736 (since 6 >=5) the rounded number will be 1740.
    now for 1432 (since 2 <5 ) the rounded number will be 1430....

I hope this will work... if not than let me know about those cases...

Happy Programming,

Answer (score 1):

very simple. try this

```
int y = 173256457;int x = (y/10)*10;
```

Now in this you can replace 10 by 100,1000 and so on....

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, this would bring 1739 to 1730 instead of 1740.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy..

int x = 1234;
int y = x - x % 10;  //It will give 1230

int y = x - x % 100; //It will give 1200

int y = x - x % 1000; //It will give 1000

The above logic will just convert the last digits to 0. If you want actual round of//
For eg. 1278 this should round off to 1280 because last digit 8 > 5 for this i wrote a function check it out.

```
 private double returnAfterRoundDigitNum(double paramNumber, int noOfDigit)  
    {  
     double tempSubtractNum = paramNumber%(10*noOfDigit);  
     double tempResultNum = (paramNumber - tempSubtractNum);  
     if(tempSubtractNum >= (5*noOfDigit))  
      {  
          tempResultNum = tempResultNum + (10*noOfDigit);  
      }  
      return tempResultNum;  
   }
```

Here pass 2 parameters one is the number and the other is position till which you have to round off.

Regards,
Abhinav

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it this way:

```
int num = 1732;
int roundedNum = Math.round((num + 9)/10 * 10);
```

This will give you 1740 as the result.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int val2 = 1732;
    val2 = (int)(Math.rint((double) i / 10) * 10);
```

The output is:1730

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the implementation of Mathutils.round() ?  It's all based on BigDecimal and string conversions.  Hard to imagine many approaches that are less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any math utils, rounding could be achieved to any unit as below:

```
double roundValue (double input, double toNearest){
//toNearest is any rounding base like 10, 100 or 1000.
    double modValue = input % toNearest;
    System.out.println(modValue);
    if(modValue == 0d){
        roundedValue = input;
    }
    else
    {
        roundedValue = ((input - modValue) + toNearest);
    }
    System.out.println(roundedValue);
    return roundedValue;
}
```