# Rounding off digit and decimals to Nearest Hundred

Tags: java, selenium

Hi i have a scenarios in which

i have to verify the integer 35.0K with 34995

i am converting 35.0 to 35000

```
String str = new Double(casha).toString().substring(0,casha.indexOf('.'));
int org=Integer.parseInt(str);
org=org*1000;
```

in  which is i have to rounded off 34995 to 35000 in my java program

i got this by doing

```
int rounded = ((34995+ 99) / 100 ) * 100;
if(org==rounded){
system.out.println("pass");
}else 
{
system.out.println("Fail");
}
```

which will result in 35000 and verifying it BUT

```
BUT it does not work for the values like 147.7K(147700) and 147661(147000)
which is 147000
```

How can i compare values like this 147.7K 123.2K how to convert .7 and 2. hundreds.

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: Look maybe at [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775866/how-to-round-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get that .7 and .2

```
String numberString = "123.4K";
numberString = numberString.replace("K", "");
Double numberDouble = new Double(numberString)*1000;
Integer numberInteger = numberDouble.intValue();
System.out.println(numberInteger);
```

Output:

```
123400
```

So, after this, you can run the approximation on both numbers and see that they match.

*also, I too recommend looking at the link provided in the comments*