# Java, how to truncate digits in a long such in a way that mimics rounding?

Tags: java, rounding

Imagine I have a long that's representing a price:

```
548880
```

Maybe this specifies a price like 54.8880.   The long form is used to transfer the data over the wire.

I'd like to simply round the price to a given precision.

For example, `54.8880 --> 54.89`, thus my final long becomes 548900.

Is it possible to round the long directly in this manner, or would I have to recast long to `BigDecimal`, round, and then back to long?

Comment: What's up with the leading 0s?

Comment: There are  [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) that can help you with this formatting.

Comment: Our prices our 8 digits, so the leading 0's are placeholders, as we could send a number like 0005 to mean 5, 005 to mean 50, 05 to mean 500 and 5 to mean 5000

Comment: Luiggi, I've seen the formatting, but that seems to be for print statements.  Would those actually change my numbers in my mathematical operations?

Comment: ***Maybe this specifies a price like 54.8880*** or maybe not, on the other side of the "wire" this:00548880 can be 54.8880 or 5.48880 or 5488.80.... how do you differentiate those???

Comment: The decimal place is sent along with the price so the other side knows how to decimalize the long.  EG, we tell it "4" to mean put the decimal place 4 places form the left (54.8880)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775866/how-to-round-integer-in-java

Comment: I mean.. maybe.  I'd like to avoid casting to double before rounding is the idea.  Can one simply truncate a long (5423243 --> 540000) without invoking a double cast?

Comment: I removed the leading zeros, as they are not relevant to our discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long n = 33333; // your number
int digit = n%10; // will return 3
if(digit < 5) 
    n -= digit; // 33330
else {n-= digit; n += 10;} // 33340
```

Change 10 to match your precision.

Comment: Thanks, this is more along the lines of what I was thinking.  Let me test it out real quick

Comment: This is def along the lines of what I want, but if I change my precision from 10 to 100, it doesn't return 33400, it returns 33310.

Comment: You have to change 10 in the last line. Also 33333 would always return 33330 because of how rounding works. 33340 was just an example.

Comment: Doh, yup just noticed this myself.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The somewhat tricky one-liner to round to multiples of 100 is:

```
(n + 50) / 100 * 100
```

Adapt the constants to round to other precisions.

Comment: I didn't actually mention this in the original quesiton, but I actually need to always round towards negative infinity.  This is pretty clever, but would it accomadate such rounding?

Comment: For positive numbers this is even simpler: n / 100 * 100